# Dojo Localization

Tags: localization, dojo

I have to **provide client side localization** (Support German and Spanish language) using Dojo to 'agent.js' file present in recordings folder, but I couldn't able to get the object.

Localization is working fine when dojo folder and recording folder present in same folder but I can't move dojo folder to 'Data' folder.

Folder Layout [as I can't post images]

```
  - Javascript
      -Adventure
         -Data
            -recordings
               -nls
                 -de
                   agent.js
                 -es
                   agent.js
                 agent.js
              agent.js
  -dojo
```

Comment: How are your module paths configured, what are you using in the call to dojo.requireLocalization?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```
dojo.registerModulePath("yourApp", "../Javascript/Adventure/Data/recordings");

dojo.requireLocalization("yourApp", "agent");
```

Comment: +1 for this answer, you should take a look at http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_config/ - see sections 'Loading Configuration' and 'Locale and Internationalization'. The dojotoolkit will ask the client browser's useragent which locale to represent (if available). **NB** The modulePath gets deprecated in 1.7+, use 'packages' instead

Comment: Hey @Marcelo, I tried your approach but i am getting **blank object**.                                                           This is the code i wrote::                                         `dojo.require("dojo.i18n"); dojo.registerModulePath("yourApp", "../Javascript/Adventure/Data/recordings"); dojo.requireLocalization("yourApp", "agent"); dojo.addOnLoad(function () { var foo = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("yourApp", "agent", "de"); });`

Comment: Hey i got the solution for dojo localization:                      For the above hierarchy this should be the code                                                                **IN recordings\agent.js file**             `dojo.provide("Data.recordings.agents");`
`dojo.require("Data.recordings.agents");`
`dojo.requireLocalization("Data","recordings"); `                   `var nls = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("centricity.recordings", "agentspane","de");`